# Wait for button to be re-enabled after fetching (wait for attribute)

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Whilst fetching data I want to disable a button. After the fetch is complete the button should be re-enabled.

Is there a way to wait for an element to have a certain attribute, or better, to **not** have a certain attribute?

The code I currently have (not working):

```
it("re-enables the test button after loading", async () => {
  getTest.mockRejectedValue("failed");

  render(<CreateItem />);

  (await screen.findByText("Test")).click();

  const testBtn = (await screen.findByText("Test")).closest("button");

  if (!testBtn) throw new Error("could not find test button");

  expect(testBtn.hasAttribute("disabled")).to.equal(
    false,
    "test button is still disabled",
  );
});
```

The same code works when checking if the button was disabled after clicking it. Probably because the component is quick enough, as it happens right at the start of the fetch implementation. Which means it could possibly fail and it would be (again) better to wait for the disabled attribute to appear.

```
// Screen.tsx
export default function Screen(): ReactElement {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(new Item());
  const [isTesting, setIsTesting] = useState(false);
  const [tests, setTests] = useState<Map<number, Test>>(new Map());

  return (
    [...]
      <form onChange={handleChange} role="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        [...]
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
          Create
        </Button>
        <Button
          color="secondary"
          disabled={isTesting}
          onClick={doTest}
          type="button"
          variant="outlined"
        >
          Test
        </Button>
      </form>
    [...]
  );

  [...]

  async function doTest() {
    setIsTesting(true);

    const needToTest = getNeedToTest();

    tests.clear();

    const all = needToTest.map(({ id }) => {
      tests.set(id, { status: "loading" });

      // Asynchronously fetch the test
      return fetchTestFor(id);
    });

    // Populate the state with the initial loading states
    setTests(new Map(tests));

    await Promise.all(all);

    // After all fetches have finished...
    setIsTesting(false);

    async function fetchTestFor(id: number) {
      const test = await getTest(id, item);

      // Update the test for specified need to test
      tests.set(id, test);

      setTests(new Map(tests));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the `CreateItem` component?

Comment: @juliomalves I added the code of the screen. I hesitate to just post code from work, even though it would probably be fine without it, I've removed a few pieces of code and altered the names of variables and the comments. Is it so rare that one wants to "wait for an attribute"?